# Is it okay to encourage class changes with magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, magic-items, party

My party consist mostly of spellcasters:

- 2 Wizards
- 1 Sorcerer
- 1 Ranger (who is new)
- 1 Rogue

The party is 5th-level, having made it this far because we had a Barbarian and a Paladin to man the front.  The Barbarian is dead (he now plays the sorcerer) and the Paladin has left due to personal responsibilities. Normally I wouldn't want to mess with the classes they like to play but some problems arose because of this party mix:

1. Combat has slowed down due to heavy spell usage. No matter how much I have applied the techniques I learned here, combat takes a moment longer due to looking up spell effects and other such minutiae.
2. The party is squishy. Having no front-liner, I find myself pulling back a touch in fear of being branded 'that deadly GM'. Often, no matter how much I tweak, combat devolves into who-wins-initiative-wins situations.

As it is, I was rolling some random treasure for the party and rolled a +2 Weapon. Now, this is the *strongest* Magic Item I am about to give out, and I could just make it a scimitar and expect that the party would give it to the Ranger but I had thought about making it a different, more strength-based weapon to encourage one of them to change into a strength-melee character if one of them dies or decides to retire their character.

Have you done this in your games?
What are the repercussions I can expect to face?
Has it resulted in class changes, as intended?

Comment: I don't understand the reluctance to kill them if they can't hang.  TPK at low levels isn't the war crime some people claim it to be.  Why are you pulling punches?  I think that's an integral part of your problem statement.  You seem to be entertaining the idea of forcing someone to do what you see as "right" with a not too subtly forced multi classing, but not willing to let their choices inform outcomes. (yes, I know low level 5e is swingy and potentially lethal).

Comment: You are supposed to have fun, and working hard not to kill them is not fun. It is not your responsibility to keep them alive with their subpar party, it was their choice.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The party is 5th-level. They got this far because they had a Barbarian and a Paladin. The Barbarian (is now the sorcerer) died and the paladin left due to IRL responsibilities.

Comment: I voted to re-open and made a few edits to account for missing words and grammar/syntax.  If you like the edit, fine, if not please re-edit to clean it up.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any more suggestions on how I can focus the question more so that it won't be opinion-based?

Answer (score 5):

**Your party is fine, don't try to force them to change. The balance you are looking for is inherent in the separate schools of magic.**

Your first problem is actually a really easy one to fix:

Have the casters make up spell casting cards for themselves so they don't have to constantly look them up. I don't mind letting new players get used to this, but if every turn is delayed as people can't make up their minds, start running the combat in real time by giving players only 20 seconds per turn to decide on an action. A caster pouring through his entire spell list deciding the perfect action can feel the real time effect of being an indecisive caster in the midst of combat this way. But suggest the cards first, then escalate to timed turns if you need to.

Your second problem doesn't actually require fixing:

With two wizards and a sorcerer, your party is fine for having tanks. If the wizards and sorcerer can't come up with a way between the three of them to not all go Evocation, then that's the parties problem and not yours. If they all want to play super nukes, great. Odds are they're going to run out of steam and get trampled by something until they prepare some utility spells or some crowd control. Casters aren't all about the WoW style super nuke. They need to experience some real hardship to start recognizing that having terrain altering effects, buffs/debuffs and straight up escape spells are absolutely essential to the class.

Basically, let them play their classes and see how the dice roll. You'd be surprised at how easy the game is to play without a tank or a healer, so long as the party can be creative and thoughtful when it comes to handling mobs.

Trying to force characters to take classes you think they should have is likely going to build some resentment when players are rolling fighters and getting bored because they want to be casters. Just let them play, throw the encounters at them, and don't be afraid to exploit obvious weaknesses they leave you. I've experienced and witnessed people try to force character class changes and it almost never ends well. If you're going to do something like this, you really have to ease a character into it very gradually, and usually with their consent and knowledge.

If they start to get mad, point out that their spell lists have a lot more than just damaging spells on them and that they should consider what they're fighting and what kind of spells can be used to counter it. Also, since you have two wizards, you can politely point out that when they level, they should never be picking the same spells because that way they can double up every level on new spells. Wizards can totally trade books and add to their known list very quickly this way. A party of three wizards can have most of the spells known in the game incredibly quickly by exploiting this particular trick.

I would recommend that if your sorcerer really clicks on this, that you give him a magical "do over" item so he can reconfigure his spells accordingly just the once.

As for combat becoming initiative wins, that's really the parties problem to deal with. If they can't survive a single round, maybe they should look into ways to make themselves a little more robust than spun glass. But that's on them, not on you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43189/discussion-on-answer-by-lino-frank-ciaralli-is-it-okay-to-encourage-class-change).